Granular weather history
Finding a website that has past temperature data (for selected weather station), as granular as possible. Ideally 120++ readings/h.
The data/information should go as farback as possible, but even one capped at 75min is okayy-usable.
Bonus:

logs all the other things like wind speed, direction, barometer, humidity, etccc.

[ Current(?) state o'art: refreshing wunderground eg kcamillb13 probably does give me the latest reading who knows, but it does not store them should I be expected to just keep refreshing and they expected to serve without throttling. ]

Requirements:

free (fine ads are ok, but no dark patterns pls)
hopefully  no requirements to sign up or subscribe stufff

